# Authenticate without entering userid and password

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, jco

In our organization we have an internal portal like `www.xyz.com` and we use SAP Web interface.

Basically I'm writing a Java code using JCo to fetch the data from SAP table. but I need to authenticate to get into the application. In this Web interface we don't enter the user name and password.

When I open the Web page it directly takes the USERID and PASSWORD from `xyz.com` portal and logs in.

Is there a way that in my Java code, I can retrieve that data (I don't want to view it, just authenticate directly using that portal) and get the data. Currently my code to retrieve data is like below.

```
JCO.createClient("SAP client", "username","password","language",
"server name","system number");
```

Here I want to get the user name and password directly.

Is there a way to get this?

Thanks

Comment: Tell use the JCO version.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that your portal is using a SSO solution?

In general it is possible by using `JAAS`.

Configure a JAAS `LoginModule`, get the username and - maybe - the password and providing that information to the `JCO` client.

Comment: Hi, I'm using 3.0.6 version